# DWR 2 to DWR 3 comet

Tags: java, dwr

I currently develop with DWR 2, but I now want to try DWR 3.
I don't understand how is possible to make comet with DWR 3. I've searched on Google many many times but I've not found any good examples.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to [configure DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/reverse-ajax/getting-started) to enable Reverse AJAX.  To start the Comet cycle, you need to request Reverse AJAX on page load: `dwr.engine.setActiveReverseAjax(true);`.  To enable full streaming, set the `init-param`: `maxWaitAfterWrite` to `-1`.  If full streaming is not what you want, you can set that to whatever poll rate you want (default is 5s).  Comet can be hard on the server, so be careful.